# Разработка аддонов NodeJS на С++. Компиляция с node-gyp и v8

Tags: node.js, gcc, g++, addons

Пишу аддон для Node.js, обеспечивающий работу с Arduino и atmega. Шаблон исходного кода (библиотеки, подключения) брал с офф. документации (https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html).

```
#include <node.h>
#include "atmelconnection.h"

namespace driver {

using v8::Function;
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Null;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Value;
// ...
```

Проблемы начинаются при "подключении" FunctionCallbackInfo, ошибка следующая:

```
 ../driver.cpp:7:12: error: ‘v8::FunctionCallbackInfo’ has not been declared
```

Этот тип данных нужен далее в коде

```
void sendCommand(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[2]);
```

Файл    binding.gyp:

```
{
"targets": [
                 {
                   "target_name": "Driver",
                    "sources": [ "driver.cpp", "atmelconnection.cpp" ]
                 }
               ]
}
```

Ниже представлен вывод того, что стоит на компьютере (компиляторы и т.д.).

```
$ node-gyp list
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.3.1
gyp info using node@0.10.25 | linux | x64
0.10.25
gyp info ok 

$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

$ uname -rp
4.2.0-35-generic x86_64

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010
```

Comment: Node.JS, наверное, старый. В прошлых версиях надо было писать `Arguments` вместо `FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>`